# Limit the scope of the overriden method in Java inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public abstract class SoftwareComponent {

    private Set<Information> generateInfo = new HashSet<Information>();
    private Set<Information>  consumeInfo = new HashSet<Information>();
    public Set<Infomation>  getGeneratedInfo() { ... }
    public Set<Information> getConsumedInfo()  {....}
}

public  class SensorDriver extends SoftwareComponent {

}

public  class Information { ... }

public class SensorMeasurement extends Information {   }

public class command extends Information {     }
```

Above mentioned code is my program Structure. Now, the situation is  Sensor Driver inherits
all its parent class method. I want to limit the scope of overridden Method  in the sensor driver.

The limit is 
"Sensor driver" can only generate "Sensor Measurement" information. 
"Sensor driver" is not allowed to consume "Command" information.

Comment: You can't.  That would break the concept of inheritance.  Anything the base class can do, your subclass needs to honor.

Comment: I can't make sense of this question. Can you perhaps change your wording?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my question: "Is there any way to restrict the scope of  overridden method in subclass in Java?"

Comment: You haven't shown any overriding methods. Please update your post with more detail showing an overriding method and explicitly indicate what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your SoftwareComponent generic and make Information a parameter:

```
public abstract class SoftwareComponent<I extends Information> {

  private Set<I> generateInfo = new HashSet<I>();
  private Set<I> consumeInfo = new HashSet<I>();
  public Set<I> getGeneratedInfo() { ... }
  public Set<I> getConsumedInfo()  {....}
}

public class SensorDriver extends SoftwareComponent<SensorMeasurement> {
}
```

Comment: Sorry ozan, I am new in stackoverflow ( just 2 days old). I have 3 reputations. With these number of reputation, I am not allowed to mark. I am really sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're looking at single inheritance as the answer, you could run into problems.  I think you actually want to use multiple inheritance (in the form of interfaces).  You should consider declaring interfaces which allow you to perform certain actions and perhaps abstract classes that implement some of those interfaces that "group" logical classes together.

As a general rule of thumb, if B is an A, it will inherit all of A.  But if B is A except for x, y, and z, you can throw an UnsupportedOperationException, which is acceptable in some cases, but you should really consider restructuring your hierarchy just a little so it all makes more sense.